# Data Collection from online Form and store data into Google Sheet

Tags: online-forms

How collect/enter data online through Form and store data in google sheet and also provide/Connect this data in simple dashboard and portal.

i want to create simple Form or Application for online data entry and collecting into google sheet and also connect this form application to simple dashboard/Portal for generate and view report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Form you create will automatically store answers in a Google sheet. You can find the link to the google sheet by selecting Responses on the top menu bar in the Google Form edit page, and then "View in Sheets". You can also click the ellipses to select an alternate destination for the responses.